# Should css animations be propagated into ShadowDOM?

Tags: polymer, css-animations, shadow-dom, custom-element

I wanted to clarify whether animations from global scope should work under ShadowDOM.
Meaning, I have class that penetrated across ShadowDOM, but animations from it doesn't work on any element under ShadowDOM.
If I add animations directly under element - everything seems to work fine.

Working: http://jsbin.com/doqotexuzi/edit?html,output
Doesn't: http://jsbin.com/rutojemoli/edit?html,output
(examples needs native ShadowDOM support, works in Chromium)

Comment: I believe this is part of a know bug discussed here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=229345

Answer (score 0):

The /deep/ shadow-piercing selector was [removed as of Chrome 63](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/10/remove-shadow-piercing).  You can easily accomplish the same in your example by styling the x-hi element, since it's direct child will inherrit, or by linking to a stylesheet used in the light DOM.